# Which Hindu god/deity has most temples?

Tags: gods, temple, india, goddess

Is there any authentic data captured by a reputed institute or organization, that clearly shows which Hindu God/Deity has highest no. of temples in India?

Does any Government body or NGO keep track of this information?

I know it is challenging to categorize what is a temple and what is not, but I feel there has to be some standard to define this and have this info. kept somewhere.

Why am I asking this question? Here is my rationale.

- This information can throw up interesting insight into the minds of those who are not much familiar with Hindu religion. 
  For example: Why is there a God like Brahma who is a well-known figure in Trinity, but whose temples are rare to find?
- It may generate more interest in a god whose temple count is more and people may want to explore more info. about the god. This way, stories will be exchanged and discussion may begin bringing more info. to the surface!

Any hints?

Comment: The two gods with the most temples are Vishnu and Shiva.  I think Shiva probably has more temples than Vishnu, but I'm not sure.

Comment: While asking this, I too had those  two in mind, but same like you, there is no proper evidence or record which can support the claim!

Comment: @AnilKumar if you see the question and discussion, it is clear that what we are looking for is actual evidence and not mere guesses like "may be ". the challenge is to find how to get the factual statistical data, without which everyone else will have their own versions and views of which god has more temples

Comment: @AADTechnical According to [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KWJsBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=There+are+more+temples+devoted+to+Hanuman+than+any+other+deity+in+India&source=bl&ots=0aGqtT39Qi&sig=EcVqqbUE95wj8_egAxWsxhXAGm8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC_pSshtbKAhUDB44KHWODAFEQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20more%20temples%20devoted%20to%20Hanuman%20than%20any%20other%20deity%20in%20India&f=false) page, **Hanuman has more temples**.

Comment: If you take linga into consideration for counting.... Shiva's idols are more... More over in South India.

Comment: It must be Shiva. He has many temples with different names all over India.

Comment: probably Ganesha (vinayaka), or Durga(amman).. almost every street corner will have small idol or temple.. in tamilnadu at least

Comment: I think shiva temples more then any other

Answer (score 1):

Even though i don't have exact numbers with me, Vishnu has the more temples (consider all forms of Vishnu). I got this rough information from a government department. Since they don't have any online presence, i cannot give you link. But each state government owns a muzrai department where they govern the govt. owned temples. These department are further divided according to district wise.

Given below is the address of Karnataka Muzrai department office:
Religious endownment commissioner office, 
Near Appex bank,
chamarajpet,
 Bangalore

Comment: Yes, I agree with Abhishek. I did not have exact count, but among all the temples I have visited, most number was for Lord Vishnu's different forms( Krishna, Ram, Vitthal, Vishnu)